# Can I target a very specific area on a Magento page with a custom module block?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I've created a very simple Magento module that just inserts a red square for now. What is the proper way to place my HTML where I'd like it on the product page?

I'm trying to place the block right above the product attributes block.

The following places the block at the bottom of the content but before the footer. I've tried targeting other blocks via `reference` but so far I've only got `content` to work. I've also tried `before="-"` and `after="-"` with no luck. It just moves my html above or below the content (as it should).

Config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <comapany_modulename>
                <class>Company_Modulename_Block</class>
        </company_modulename>
    </blocks>
</global>

<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <modulename module="Company_ModuleName">
                <file>company/Module.xml</file>
            </modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/company/module.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="company_modulename/blockphpname"
               name="module.productview"
               template="company/template.phtml" >
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

app/code/local/company/module/Block/block.php

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Blockname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function getDate()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        return urlencode($date).' test';
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/company/template.phtml

```
<div style="padding:50px; background:red; float: left; width:100px; height:100px;">test: <?php echo $this->getDate() ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

i am changing Module name `module to MyModule`

Extension is wrong path and Wrong folder paths `app/code/local/Company/MyModule/Block/`
name="category.products"

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="comapany_modulename/block"
               name="module.productview"
               template="company/template.phtml" after="category.products" >
        </block>
    </reference>
```

`Block file name  should start with cap word`  app/code/local/Company/Mymodule/Block/`Block.php`.

Also, class name is wrong
class `Company_MyModule_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`

If it is not working then change

**Add** `output="toHtml"` to layout.xml

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="company_modulename/blockphpname"
               name="module.productview" output="toHtml"
               template="company/template.phtml" >
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: Adding output="toHtml creates two instances of my block, One below the content and one below the footer.

Comment: No, It is displaying on my page but not in the right spot